# deal with special characters in NSURL

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurl

i have this code to url of image , i have little problem with my url it contain \u and xcode consider it as special character So i escape it by adding \u in my url 
but when i pass it

```
fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:\\www.school-link.net\\uploads\\%@",image_url];
    NSLog(@"file path  %@",fullPath);
    //i try escape space by this code it dosnt work 
   //fullPath = [fullPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:fullPath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];



 AFHTTPRequestOperation *posterOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    posterOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [posterOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
        image_view.image = responseObject;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image request failed with error: %@", error);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:posterOperation];
    [posterOperation start];
```

it give me error , any ideas 
thank you all

> image request failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x8f9f900 {NSUnderlyingError=0x9a94cf0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is malformed.  Right now you have:

```
http:\\www.school-link.net\\uploads\\%@
```

Those backslashes should instead be forward slashes.  Ex:

```
http://www.school-link.net/uploads/%@
```

Now you can append `image_url` to the URL, and presuming `image_url` doesn't cause the URL to be malformed, your request will go through.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUTF8String encoding. It will solve the problem. For example

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:yourURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

A line using this is commented in your code.